# Woocommerce checkout page error for my custom payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, checkout

```
  {"result":"failure","messages":"<ul class=\"woocommerce-error\">\n\t\t\t<li>
    We were unable to process your order, please try again.<\/li>\n\t<\/ul>\n","refresh":"true","reload":"false"}
```

I know this is from  the
Woocommerce/include/class-wc-checkout.php file.

I found some links related to my question, but they haven't solved my issue.
[Woocommerce plugin gives 'We were unable to process your order'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318303/woocommerce-plugin-gives-we-were-unable-to-process-your-order)
https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201888769-checkout-fails-to-submit

Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this.

Comment: Did you try/check all the suggested actions? Right now your question is like "My car won't start, does anyone know why?". There is just not enough information to go by.

Comment: @RST Yes i try and one more things is when i load page it show this kind of error in Firebug - 'sitename.com/checkout/?wc-ajax=checkout' (500 (internal server error))

Comment: That means there is an error in your code. Still not enough information to work with. I doubt anyone will be able to help. I think you are better off posting this to the woocommerce forum. People will want to know if it never worked or stopped working, if it acts the same way with a default WP theme, if your software is up to date, what PHP version you are on, what payment system you are using and so on, and so on. Stackoverflow is for questions about code you created that doesn't work (as expected). Your issue is different.